# C++ template using multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

Is it possible in C++ to write this:

```
template <typename T, size_t dim, size_t len>
using A = /* something */;
```

that will make these two lines equivalent:

```
/* 1 */ A<int, 3, 5> a;   A<char, 5, 3> c;

/* 2 */ int a[5][5][5];   char c[3][3][3][3][3];
```

?

Comment: Please explain more about "equivalent". Maybe show some lines of code you want to work  and what effect you want them to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is it possible?* Yes, you can do arbitrarily complex calculations at compile-time, so there certainly is a solution.

The most straightforward way is to just use template recursion, like so:

```
template <class T, size_t dim, size_t len>
struct A_helper {
    using type = typename A_helper<T, dim - 1, len>::type[len];
};

template <class T, size_t len>
struct A_helper<T, 0, len> {
    using type = T;
};

template <class T, size_t dim, size_t len>
using A = typename A_helper<T, dim, len>::type;
```

See it on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfc9052b30bce553

Comment: Can I directly use `template<typename T, size_t dim, size_t len> using A = A<T, dim-1, len>[len]`?

Comment: i.e. is a helper class necessary?

Comment: @iBug You need something you can partially specialize in order to provide the base case, and alias templates cannot be (partially or wholly) specialized.